# Lightroom totally resetting image on undo

Tags: post-processing, lightroom-4

I'm having an issue with LR at the moment where I make a tonne of edits but if I make a single mistake I hit undo and it totally resets the entire image adjustments. This is getting extremely stressful because it means that if I make a mistake I have to start again on the image. If it's a picture my client has already chosen it means potentially they could end up with a different looking image.

There is sometimes a triangle that appears in the bottom right of the editor window and says something about new stuff (sorry cant remember) being available for that image but after downloading it did nothing and now I rarely see it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are asking but I'll try :)

There is a History window in Develop module. So you can always redo all your steps after you've undone them or go back in history to any step (their number is limited and you can set in Settings).

[image: Lightroom History]

You can also make a Snapshot of your image and come back to it every time even after you have done a lot of other editings after that.

Read also [Manage image history and snapshots](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/develop-module-options.html#manage_image_history_and_snapshots)  on Lightroom Help site.